# finding possible pairs of rank and signature

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

> For a quadratic form in $3$ variable over $\mathbb{R}$, let $r$ be its
>   rank and $s$ be its signature. The number of possible pairs $(r,s)$ is
>
> $(a)$ $13$.
>
> $(b)$ $9$.
>
> $(c)$ $10$.
>
> $(d)$ $16$.

Since a quadratic form in $3$ variables is a $3\times 3$ matrix, it has a possible rank of $0,1,2,3$ ($0$ if we allow the quadratic form identically zero, hence null matrix). So The answer should be a multiple of $4$, so option $(d)$ should have been correct. But the answer is given to be $10$. I don't get what's going wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various definitions of "signature" in the literature.One definition given by Wolfram Math World is "the signature  is sometimes defined to be the number   of positive squared terms in its reduced form" I'll use this definition . Upon diagonalization, rank=number of non-zero terms, signature =number of positive terms. So $$ \text { if }r=3, s=3,2,1, \text { or } 0$$$$ \text { if }r=2, s=2,1, \text { or } 0$$$$ \text { if }r=1, s=1, \text { or } 0$$$$ \text { if }r=0, s= 0$$  Thus there are 10 possibilities for $(r,s)$

Comment: If I follow the definition of "signature" that I was taught, then I am getting only 6 pairs, namely $(0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,2),(3,1)$, and $(3,3)$. According to your solution, the signature ($s$) of a quadratic form is what I know as the index ($p$) of the same. They are connected through the following equation: $s+r=2p$ (an even number). So, I guess the answer to this problem boils down to the definition of "signature!"

Comment: Sorry, earlier I missed the following $4$ pairs: $(1,-1), (2,-2), (3,-1),$ and $(3,-3).$ So, even if I follow my definition of "signature," the answer doesn't change. Wow!